# how to insert elements in the array ,which has space as the next field for the db mysql via php

Tags: php

My array looks like

```
Array ( [0] => lvenkat anarajam 1, venuv vparames 2, sprabhud girshank 1, pmuralid akandare 1, vparames rahulg2 3, sprabhud kseshadr 1, lvenkat rganesam 1, lvenkat ssihi 1, svarghes denmathe 2, vparames shsreena 2, suniljo bakrish2 1, suniljo bkganesh 1, suniljo msomakum 3 )
```

mytable in mysql

```
Director  Manager  Count
```

how to insert the array into my db considering the empty space in the  elements as a next field?

for example I want my table looks like

```
Director  Manager  Count 

lvenkat    anarajam  1
```

I have tried the `foreach`  loop for insert but I don't know how to separate the space as new field or variable.

```
foreach ($array as $val) {

      $data = implode ($val); //confuse starts here 

      $sql = "INSERT INTO report (Director, Manager, Count)
VALUES (?, ?, '?)";


  }
```

Comment: "_considering the empty space in the elements as a next field_" Can you explain this a little more? What empty space? Also, maybe consider reworking the output of your "array"

Comment: Thats an array of one item, so basically just a comma delimited string

Comment: You should be using `explode`, not `implode`. And you need to provide the delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input array is not really anything other than a comma delimited string that happens to appear in the the first occurance of an array.

Using the `mysqli_` API and a couple of explodes however you can make meaningful data out of that rather unfriendly array.

```
$array = ['lvenkat anarajam 1, venuv vparames 2, sprabhud girshank 1, pmuralid akandare 1, vparames rahulg2 3, sprabhud kseshadr 1, lvenkat rganesam 1, lvenkat ssihi 1, svarghes denmathe 2, vparames shsreena 2, suniljo bakrish2 1, suniljo bkganesh 1, suniljo msomakum 3'];
//remove leading space from 2nd, 3rd.... records
$array[0] = str_replace(', ',',',$array[0]);

$records = explode(',', $array[0]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO report (Director, Manager, Count) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
// prepare once reuse many times
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

foreach ($records as $fields) {
    list( $Director,$Manager,$count) = explode( ' ', $fields );

    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $Director,$Manager,$count);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

> WARNING: If any of the fields themselves contain a space this will not work as expected
>
> I would strongly recommend that you look at how you create that array and make each record appear in its own occurance of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly then perhaps the following might help ~ though it is unclear which database api you are using - assumed mysqli here.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO report (Director, Manager, Count) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bind_param('ssi',$first,$last,$int);

foreach( $array[0] as $key => $value ){
    list( $first,$last,$int )=explode( ' ', $value );
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

As pointed out... the first entry in the array is a string so a little rewrite

```
    /* to rebuild the array as per question... */
    $str='lvenkat anarajam 1, venuv vparames 2, sprabhud girshank 1, pmuralid akandare 1, vparames rahulg2 3, sprabhud kseshadr 1, lvenkat rganesam 1, lvenkat ssihi 1, svarghes denmathe 2, vparames shsreena 2, suniljo bakrish2 1, suniljo bkganesh 1, suniljo msomakum 3';
    $array=array($str);


    $src = $array[0];
    $pieces = explode(',',$src);



    $sql = "INSERT INTO report (Director, Manager, Count) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi',$first,$last,$int);



    foreach( $pieces as $key => $value ){
        list( $first,$last,$int )=explode( ' ', $value );
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Comment: can you please edit this for mysqli query. I'm not using pdo. I just put question mark for the values not for insert statement :)

Comment: that is based upon `mysqli` not `PDO`

Comment: Hi Ram, I think you missed that that array is really no more than a comma delimited string which happens to exist in occurance [0] of an array.

Comment: ah... you are right when I look at that again. Thank you @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

So, let's start. You have an array which has the values to be filled, each row separated by a comma.

So, first of all, we will make an array of each row.

Then, within those rows, we will be exploding further for fields by a space.

```
foreach($array as $val)
{
    // Getting all the rows
    $rows = explode(', ', $val);

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        // Getting the values
        $row_values = explode(' ', $row);

        /* Your database insert command goes here... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can first explode the input by a comma delimiter then apply again for-each on exploded array & prepare array for inserting records. So, You direct import created an array in SQL method

```
foreach($array as $val) {
  $data = explode(', ', $val);

   foreach( $data as $row ) {
   $strInsertData = explode(' ', $row);
  $arrInsert[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($strInsertData[0]).'", "'.$strInsertData[1].'", ' .$strInsertData[2].')';
  }
}   
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (Director, Manager, Count) VALUES '.implode(',', $arrInsert));
```

Comment: ?? Using the `mysql_` API is rather short sighted as that is a dead API and as commented in @ramraider answer, the OP is using the`mysqli_` API

Comment: still you are using mysql ??

Comment: @Aroon I just gave example, which I have used at the time of college. We can replace MySQL with mysqlI. But the method which I have mentioned which will give an answer about what we want.